# Navigation from menu frame to content frame

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, navigationservice

I have found this issue here:
[WPF Navigate Pages from outside frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28139522/wpf-navigate-pages-from-outside-frame)
But never solved, I have the same issue and same window structure:

```
<DockPanel>
    <Frame x:Name="Menu" Source="/Menu.xaml" NavigationUiVisibility="Hidden" />
    <Frame x:Name="Content" Source="/Welcome.xaml" NavigationUiVisibility="Hidden" />
</DockPanel>
```

As you can see, the frames contains some default pages, and Menu frame displays the menu buttons:

```
<Grid>
    <Button x:Name="Contact" Click="Contact_Click" />
    <Button x:Name="Discussion" Click="Discussion_Click" />
</Grid>
```

What I want to do is to change the source in Content, using the buttons in menu, I have already tried:

```
private void Contact_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MainWindow mainWindow = new MainWindow();
    mainWindow.Content.NavigationService.Navigate("/Contact.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
}
```

Sideways, do you think that is better option to take the menu directly into the main window instead of having it inside a different frame?

Comment: You're creating a new window on each button click (and it stays hidden). Are you sure you really wanted this?

Comment: Yeah, I do not really need the navigation UI since I have the menu page displaying in the left Frame, I actually did not wanted to create a new window for click, just wanted to change the page in the right-sided frame by clicking the button in the left-sided frame, but i cannot navigate since I am trying to trigger the navigation service for a different page.